# Использование прокси в cUrl php

Tags: php, curl, proxy

Имеется код

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, "51.222.173.54:3128");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTPS);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://ip.bablosoft.com");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($curl);
    echo curl_error($curl);
```

И он не работает, точнее прокси выдают Failed to connect to 51.222.173.54 port 3128: Connection timed out
Это паблик прокси, тоже самое происходит с теми же HTTPS **приватными** проксями.

Comment: много левых констант используешь, вот необходимый минимум https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy

Comment: в приватных прокси пароль вводишь? бесплатные выкинь.

Comment: @Jean-Claude, на локальной машине все ок, на сайте просто пустота) значит хостинг мозги делает, не подскажите, может что то нужно включить, проверить?

Comment: включи вывод всех ошибок https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display